# My React webpage no longer shows my dynamic list of images

Tags: reactjs, image

After an update, this part of my code that shows object module in the image src instead of the path to the image:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function AboutScreen() {
    var imageCorpList = [];
    var imageLangList = [];
    var imageEducList = [];
    function importAll(r) {
        return r.keys().map(r);
    }
    imageCorpList = importAll(require.context('../res/images/corplogos/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    imageLangList = importAll(require.context('../res/images/proglogos/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    imageEducList = importAll(require.context('../res/images/educlogos/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    return <div>
        <div className="image-show">
            <ul className="corp-list logo-list">
                {imageCorpList.map(image => (
                <li className="fade-in">
                    <img className="logo" src={image}></img>
                </li>   
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

EDIT:

Adding .default to the image solves the problem, however i have no idea why i now require to do this.

```
<img className="logo" key={image} src={image.default}></img>
```

Comment: You mentioned an update of some sort; can you please elaborate on what exactly was updated that caused the output to change?

Comment: it was a recent npm upgrade, but i have no much clue what package deals with mapping other than react itself.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that the lists are raw variables and not `state`?  I'm not that familiar with webpack's `require.context` but it looks like it takes a "mode" arg and that the default is `async` rather than `sync`.  https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

Comment: @LindaPaiste you seem to have a lead, the package does indeed seem to be updated very regularly which could explain the sudden changes needed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you updated to **npm 7** then `require()` won't work. they made this change in this new update.

> **Breaking changes** Since the new version is considered a major version it'll come with a couple of breaking changes. Here are some:
>
> - You can no longer use `require()` npm's internal modules. Npm now uses    the `package.exports` field.

https://justfrontendthings.com/post/npm-7-now-standard

Comment: Seems to be the case! Then what is the better way to replace the require method in my code?

Comment: what is the value of `imageCorpList`?